# How to assign dynamic values fetched from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
location=new Array('display1','display2');
album1=new Array("images/1.png","images/2.png");
album2=new Array("images/a.png","images/b.png");
function slide(albumName,position,sequence)//albumName will contain album1 or album2,position will denote index in albumName elements, sequence will denote index in location array
{ 
   var path=albumName+"["+position+"]";
   document.location[sequence].src=path;
}




 <button onclick="slide('album1',0,1)>Slide</button> //Call in HTML
```

I want to fetch dynamic values inside funtion to make statement look like for example: document.display1.src="images/1.png"; But above code doesnt work. Any corrections that I may do?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, don't use the object constructors to create variables. `location = ['display1', 'display2']`, etc. is the proper way to create arrays. To access the variables, I would put them in an `albums` object. Then you can say `albums[albumName]` to get the array you want. You can then access that array however you need.

Comment: How can I access array stated by albums[albumName]?

Comment: I have working code to do that in my answer. Check down below

Answer (score 0):

To access the arrays with your image paths, I would put them in an `albums` object. Then you can say `albums[albumName]` to get the array you want. From there, you can simply access the element you want by saying `album[position]`. I didn't exactly understand what you were trying to do with the sequence, but I am pretty sure that was not your issue - you just needed to know how to get the correct path.

```js
var albums = {
  album1: ["images/1.png", "images/2.png"],
  album2: ["images/a.png", "images/b.png"]
};

function slide(albumName, position, sequence) //albumName will contain album1 or album2,position will denote index in albumName elements, sequence will denote index in location array
{
  var album = albums[albumName]; 
  var path = album[position];
  console.log(path);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="slide('album1',0,1)">Slide</button>
```

Comment: how do I access array and use its value in document.arrayName[index].src ? It works with console.log() but I want to use it with document.someName.src and its not working

Comment: @regex What you're asking for doesn't make much sense. `arrayName[index]` gives you a string. Then you are trying to set the `src` property on that string. Which... will work, but it will not do what you think it will. Are you trying to set the src property on a DOM element? I am not seeing any DOM elements in your original question, so I didn't assume anything.

Comment: document.location[sequence].src=path; I want to use array element ie. stated by location[sequence] in document.LOCATION[SEQUENCE].src=path; Your answer worked to fetch string in path but the location[sequence] doesn't work

Comment: I tried document.getElementById(someVariable).src instead of document.location[sequence].src and gave ID to my html element and it worked

Comment: @regex Exactly. That worked because you are now setting the src property of a DOM element, rather than the src property on a string inside of the document.location array. Does the difference between the two make sense?

Comment: @regex Awesome =) Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it was useful to solving your original issue.